# Conditional aggregation in SQL Server based on a column value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, conditional-statements, aggregation

My data is something like:

```
IdType     Date        ActualEst      Value     PriceType
  1        01-06         A            1          Settle
  1        02-06         A            2          Settle
  1        02-06         F            3          Settle
  1        03-06         A            4          Settle
  2        01-06         A            5          Settle
  2        02-06         A            6          Settle
  2        03-06         F            7          Settle
```

I want to do a average on "Value" column, grouping on "IdType" and "PriceType" columns such that if for a particular Date (column), ActualEst has records for both 'A' and 'F', I choose 'A' over 'F', otherwise any of them if only one of them exists for a Date.

So, for above data I should be picking these records for averaging Value:

```
IdType      Date           ActualEst       Value     PriceType
  1          01-06           A              1          Settle
  1          02-06           A              2          Settle
  1          03-06           A              4          Settle
```

as for date of 02-06 both 'A' and 'F' records exist and I give priority to 'A' if both types of records exist for a date.

second group..

```
IdType      Date           ActualEst       Value     PriceType
  2          01-06           A              5          Settle
  2          02-06           A              6          Settle
  2          03-06           F              7          Settle
```

and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Row_number() the rows according to the priority needed and select only top priority rows:

```
with tbl as ( 
    -- source data
    select * from
    (values 
         (1 ,'01-06','A',1,'Settle')
        ,(1 ,'02-06','A',2,'Settle')
        ,(1 ,'02-06','F',3,'Settle')
        ,(1 ,'03-06','A',4,'Settle')
        ,(2 ,'01-06','A',5,'Settle')
        ,(2 ,'02-06','A',6,'Settle')
        ,(2 ,'03-06','F',7,'Settle')
    ) t (IdType, [Date],ActualEst,Value,PriceType)
), 
-- the query
prioritized as(
    select IdType, [Date],ActualEst,Value,PriceType,
      rn = row_number() over(partition by IdType, [Date] order by ActualEst)
    from tbl
)
select IdType, [Date], avg(value) v
from prioritized 
where rn=1
group by IdType, [Date];
```

Answer (score 0):

With UNION ALL you get the rows on which you will group:

```
select * from tablename where ActualEst = 'A'
union all
select t.* from tablename t where ActualEst = 'F'
and not exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where IdType = t.IdType and Date = t.Date and ActualEst = 'A'
)
```

Then use it like this:

```
select
  t.IdType, t.Date, avg(value) averagevalue
from (
    select * from tablename where ActualEst = 'A'
    union all
    select t.* from tablename t where ActualEst = 'F'
    and not exists (
      select 1 from tablename
      where IdType = t.IdType and Date = t.Date and ActualEst = 'A'
    )
) t
group by t.IdType, t.Date
```

Comment: hey @forpas just curious if we can face efficiency issues here, my data is in millions.

Comment: *my data is in millions* in this case there is always a performance issue. You need an index on `ActualEst` for sure and you must try all the solutions you have.